# Group columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have the table `clients`:

```
client_id   name   class_id
101      Mark     2
132      David    3
199      Anna     1
199      Anna     1
```

and the table `class`:

```
class_id   name
1          Bronze
2          Gold
3          Platinum
```

how can I display in 2 columns with nicknames `Class` and `Clients` the number of customers that belong
in each of the three categories (Gold, Platinum, Bronze).

```
Class       Clients
Gold           1
Platinum       1
Bronze         2
```

and finally how can I display the details of all customers (except `class_id`) grouped based on the class category (ie Golden, Platinum, Bronze)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest you read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to show us what you have attempted so far. In short, you're looking for `JOIN` to combine table data, `GROUP BY` to aggregate your resultset, and `COUNT()` to get the number of clients. Also, to clarify your data, is Anna (client_id 199) supposed to exist twice in the `clients` table?

Comment: No sry it was a typo. Clients ids are unique

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you need `count` and `group by`.

```
select
    cl.name as class,
    count(c.*) as clients
from class cl
join clients c
on cl.class_id = c.class_id

group by
    cl.name

order by
    clients,
    class;
```

Output:

```
| class    | clients |
| -------- | ------- |
| Gold     | 1       |
| Platinum | 1       |
| Bronze   | 2       |
```